# How can I make my python program choose option by itself randomly if I kept it in one variable?

Tags: python

If I have made a variable which has like
a = apple, banana, orange
than how can I make my python program choose one randomly by itself

I had made a variable which had four options
a = addition, subtraction, multiplication
and I want my python to print one randomly by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your variable is a `list` (or just it's subscriptable, like a tuple ,etc..) you can do by:

```
import random

l = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
print(random.choice(l))
```

Comment: Doesn't have to be a list - just needs to be subscriptable

Comment: @Cobra yes. I use as example a list, since the OP is a beginner